# django url patterns error , id not passed to view.

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i try to create rest api, but got stuck on generating url.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^api/shop/', include(('shop.api.urls', 'shop'), namespace='api-shop',)), ]
```

also tried as

```
path('api/shop/', include(('shop.api.urls', 'shop'), namespace='api-shop',)),
```

in shop/api/urls.py i wrote

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(P<id>\d+)/$', ShopRudView.as_view(), name='shop-rud')
```

]

and in shop/api/views.py i using drf library generics views to create

```
class ShopRudView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
lookup_field = 'id'
serializer_class = ShopSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return Shop.objects.all()
```

and when I enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shop/1 i get

ing the URLconf defined in untitled1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
shop/
^api/shop/ ^(P\d+)/$ [name='shop-rud']
The current path, api/shop/1, didn't match any of these.

How to fix that?

Comment: tried, got same response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `?` in your regex:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', ShopRudView.as_view(), name='shop-rud')
```

Or, if you want to use `path`:

```
path('<int:id>/', ShopRudView.as_view(), name='shop-rud')
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django 3.1.1

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/<int:id>/', views.EmployeeDetailsCBV.as_view()),
]

url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/3/
```

in Django 3 **'(?Pd+)/$'** won't work.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/overview/